# PInvoke struct with array of unspecified length

Tags: c#, pinvoke

**C definitions**

```
typedef struct {
    const uint8_t* buf;
    int bufLen;
} Info;


int Foo(Info* info);
```

**C# definitions**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Info
{
     // [MarshalAs( ??? )]
     public byte[] buf;
     int bufLen
}    

[DllImport(...)]
public static extern int Foo(ref Info info);
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what to specify for the `MarshalAs` attribute on `byte[] buf` in the C# struct definition. The buffer is allocated on the .NET side, and its length is known at call time.

In a simple little test:

```
var info = new Info {
    buf = new byte[] {0x40, 0x50, 0x60, 0x70},
    bufLen = 4,
};

Foo(ref info);
```

Everything seems to be working correctly, but in fact the data in my buffer is incorrect.  Printing it out from the DLL I see `01 00 80 00` - not sure what that is.

I've tried:

- No `MarshalAs`
- `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]`

and nothing works.

In general, I really don't know the best way to debug these kinds of problems either.

Comment: A struct like this is difficult to marshal automatically, you have to do it yourself.  Declare *buf* as IntPtr and use Marshal.AllocHGlobal to allocate the memory for it.  Marshal.Copy to fill it.  Watch out what happens on the unmanaged side, you'll have lots of trouble if it stores the pointer or a copy of the struct.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, that worked. Why is the CLR unable to handle this automatically? My first guess would be that it doesn't look at `Info` to see how to marshal any of its elements - instead it just looks at the size of `Info` and copies that many bytes.

Comment: It could but it is just too dangerous.  Native code is likely to dereference the pointer later when the array isn't pinned anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant It could, but how is that any different from the scenario where a `byte[]` is marshalled as a parameter?

Comment: It is not, that certainly can go wrong too.  Just more likely since it is wrapped in a struct.  The problem of the difference between a shallow and a deep copy is everywhere.

Comment: @HansPassant Makes sense. I guess this raises the questions "where do you draw the line? how many levels deep do you go?" I posted an answer that seems to do the trick in this case.

Comment: @HansPassant These are the cases where I wish `MarshalAs` on `struct` declarations supported a variant of the `SizeParamIndex` parameter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per Hans Passant's suggestion, I implemented the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Info : IDisposable
{
    private IntPtr buf;
    private int bufLen;

    public Info(byte[] buf) : this() {
        this.buf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buf.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(buf, 0, this.buf, buf.Length);
        this.bufLen = buf.Length;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (buf != IntPtr.Zero) {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buf);
            buf= IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late..  but just in case if some one come here for an answer.

I finally came up with next solution for similar exercise.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Info
{
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
     public byte[] buf;
     int bufLen
}
```

**From MSDN**

> Arrays can be marshaled as UnmanagedType.ByValArray, which
>   requires you to set the MarshalAsAttribute.SizeConst field. The size
>   can be set only as a constant.

In my case the buffer size is 8 bytes.

Comment: I am not sure how this answer is relevant? The OP clearly says he does not know the size of the buffer before hand.

Comment: @9ee1 you are right. I missed _"and its length is known at call time"_ from topic and was confused by _"In a simple little test:"_ code example.